# My jquery not working not picking selector

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery that does this

if I press `ctrl` and `i` it inserts `-i- -.i-` and the cursor is placed between.

Similarly if `ctrl` and `b` it inserts `-b- -.b-`

And if `ctrl` `u` it creates `-u- -.u-`

But these functions doesn't seem to work

https://jsfiddle.  net/2Luc5x3k/1/ can anyone check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yess it works. Fire the function asap the document is ready.

Ummm, put all the code inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Your textarea code :)
});
```

Comment: Lemme try. Hope it helps

Comment: YASSSSSSS! IT DID :D

Comment: Welcome :) make your way npw